# LongListSelector not binding a array of data Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I am using LongListSelector and trying to bind an array. But no data is getting displayed. Following is my code please let me know what i am doing wrong?

**XAML**

```
  <phone:LongListSelector Name="peopleLongListSelector"   
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentData}"
                                            GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource LongListSelectorGroupHeaderTemmplate}"
                                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LongListSelectorItemTemplate}"
                                            HideEmptyGroups ="true" 
                                            IsGroupingEnabled ="true" 
                                            LayoutMode="List">
            </phone:LongListSelector>




<DataTemplate x:Key="LongListSelectorGroupHeaderTemmplate">
        <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="5">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderThickness="2"  
                                       Width="62" Height="62" Margin="0,0,18,0"                  
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                               Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" 
                                               FontSize="48"
                                               Padding="6"
                                               FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="LongListSelectorItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,4">
            <Image Width="62" Height="62" Source="{Binding Image}" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**C#**

```
  public class Component
    {
        public string Guid {get; set;}
        public string Name{get; set;}
        public Item[] Items{get; set;}
    }



    public class Item
        {
           public string Title{get; set;}
            public string Subtitle{get; set;}
            public string Date{get; set;}
         }

       public class MainLstViewModel : BaseViewModel
        {
             private Component[] ComponentData;
             public MainLstViewModel()
             {
               ComponentData = Proxy.GetDataAsync();
             }
        }
```

Comment: You are gettingr you data async - and I guess that your LLS is not updated - you have Binding but without INotifyPropertyChanged. Try to implement that interface and run OnPropertyChanged(). Or maybe use ObservableCollection instead of ComponentData array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some attributes in your Class and binding different in xaml

```
 <phone:LongListSelector Name="peopleLongListSelector"   
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentData}"
                                            GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource LongListSelectorGroupHeaderTemmplate}"
                                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LongListSelectorItemTemplate}"
                                            HideEmptyGroups ="true" 
                                            IsGroupingEnabled ="true" 
                                            LayoutMode="List">
            </phone:LongListSelector>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="LongListSelectorGroupHeaderTemmplate">
            <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="5">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderThickness="2"  
                                           Width="62" Height="62" Margin="0,0,18,0"                  
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                                   Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" 
                                                   FontSize="48"
                                                   Padding="6"
                                                   FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>    
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LongListSelectorItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,4">

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: In Listview LongListSelectorGroupHeaderTemmplate I am binding Name Property of Component class. Even that is not getting binded...?? Have you tried it in a sample app?

Comment: do you have items inside

Comment: Yes i have items and multiple component. Did you tried this code. Is this working for you?